# Comparing two databases in MS Access: is it feasible and how?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, comparison

I am attempting to compare two inventory lists; the current month vs. the previous month.  This data is housed in two separate tables.

The two schemata are slightly different, one file uses `double` for numerical values, whereas the other employs `decimal`.

I would like to compare where new ItemIDs were added or removed in comparison with the data from the previous month, as well as the value changes.

Is something like this possible in Access, or would I be better suited to import the data into MS SQL Server?

Also, can this comparison be accomplished solely with queries, or am I required to write some VBA?

Comment: I would probably look at a self outer join for this.

Comment: Tables are currently in ACCDB format, but I can convert and upload to a new MS SQL Server database if needed.  I only want to consider this if the comparison is not feasible in Access due to system resource limitations.  Also, from what I can tell, SQL Server is a more efficient database engine overall.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access is quite happy to compare decimal and double

```
SELECT "In 1" As Diff, Invent1.ID, Invent1.Amount, Invent2.Amount
FROM Invent1 LEFT JOIN Invent2 ON Invent1.ID = Invent2.ID
WHERE Invent2.ID Is Null

UNION
SELECT "In 2" As Diff, Invent2.ID, Invent1.Amount, Invent2.Amount
FROM Invent2 LEFT JOIN Invent1 ON Invent2.ID = Invent1.ID
WHERE Invent1.ID Is Null

UNION
SELECT "Amount" As Diff, Invent1.ID, Invent1.Amount, Invent2.Amount
FROM Invent1 INNER JOIN Invent2 ON Invent1.ID = Invent2.ID
WHERE [Invent1].[Amount]<>[Invent2].[Amount]
```

You might like to change the last union, depending on your data:

```
SELECT "Amount" As Diff, Invent1.ID, Invent1.Amount, Invent2.Amount
FROM Invent1 INNER JOIN Invent2 ON Invent1.ID = Invent2.ID
WHERE CCur([Invent1].[Amount])<>CCur([Invent2].[Amount])
```

Or better:

```
UNION SELECT "Amount" As Diff, Invent1.ID, Invent1.Amount, Invent2.Amount
FROM Invent1 INNER JOIN Invent2 ON Invent1.ID = Invent2.ID
WHERE CCur(Nz([Invent1].[Amount],0))<>CCur(Nz([Invent2].[Amount],0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    t2.*
FROM Table1 t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Id = t1.Id
WHERE 1=1
AND t1.Field1 <> t2.Field1 
AND t1.Field2 <> t2.Field2
etc.
```

This will get you the raw data. Then you can add to the WHERE to filter against the NULLS or whatever else. Missing entries on the left table would indicate stuff that has been added. Missing entries on the right table (t2) will show what was removed.

I'm not sure if FULL OUTER JOINS are available in msaccess but they should be in the query designer: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.  The two lists are present in separate tables, not a single table.

Comment: You should still be able to match up the similar columns, as long as the meaning is the same, and filter.